# Racket procedure "integral" which returns double argument procedure representing function

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

I need help with simple task at my university. Im stuck in a moment how to represent process of
integration without given (a b).
I have to define procedure (integral f prec) - which takes integrated procedure and precision-number of
iterations for estimating integral with sum = (b-a)/prec .The procedure should output double argument procedure so by entering a and b we can calculate our integral.

```
> ( define foo ( integral ( lambda (x) 10) 1000) )
> ( foo 0 10)
99.9999999999986
> ( define foo ( integral ( lambda (x) x) 1000) )
> ( foo 9 10)
9.499500000000001
> ( foo 0 10)
49.95000000000001
> ( define foo ( integral sin 1000) )
```

Moreover I have to use procedure defined for sumation:

```
(define (sum term a next b)
      (if (> a b)
          0
          (+ (term a)
             (sum term (next a) next b))))
```

I tried to figure it out with lambda expression but I'm new into that course and have very little time.

I found some piece of code for Simpson's integral that may be helpful.

```
 (define (simpson-integral f a b n)
      (define h (/ (- b a) n))
      (define (next x) (+ x (* 2 h)))
      (* (/ h 3) (+ (f a)
                    (* 4 (sum f (+ a h) next (- b h)))
                    (* 2 (sum f (+ a (* 2 h)) next (- b (* 2 h))))
                    (f b))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `sum` is your `sum` with minor tweak: `>` is replaced with `>=`. 
Function `integral` returns two-argument lambda and after call on numbers, whole interval between numbers is divided into `prec` intervals (for example, 1000 intervals) and area of rectangles in intervals is summed together.
`Next` is function, that returns next interval for given number. (*For example, you have 1000 intervals between 0 and 10, so 0 => 0.01 or 5.55 => 5.56.*)
`Term` is function for computing area of one rectangle. One side is length of interval and one side is minimum from *f(x)* and *f(x+next)*, these values are multiplied.

```
(define (sum term a next b)
      (if (>= a b)
          0
          (+ (term a)
             (sum term (next a) next b))))

(define (integral f prec)
  (lambda (a b)
    (sum (lambda (t)
           (* (min (f t)
                   (f (+ t (/ (- b a) prec))))
              (/ (- b a) prec)))
         a
         (lambda (n)
           (+ n (/ (- b a) prec)))
         b)))

((integral (lambda (x) (+ (* 2 x) 3)) 1000) 2 5) => almost 30
```